# Laravel Call to undefined method on a method I created

Tags: php, laravel

Uploaded my Laravel project to Shared Hosting and I'm getting this error:

> **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::shared_globals()**

shared_globals() returns an array of data that other routes will use and is in the web.php file:

```
function shared_globals()
 {
    return [ some array ];
 }
```

And then in my routes I call the shared_globals function:

```
Route::get('/abc', function() {
   return view('abc', self::shared_globals()); 
});
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Where is `shared_globals` defined at?

Comment: where is the shared globals function defined? in which class or file?

Comment: @aynber I updated my question. it's in web.php same as routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've declared it in the same file and without any scope, Directly use the function then and don't use self

```
Route::get('/abc', function() {
   return view('abc', shared_globals()); 
});
```

I think this should work, but I feel that you are trying to solve a problem the wrong way since you should not declare a function like that in the routes file.